# Can't find scheduled task in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I added a custom task to startup my Calendar app (Windows 10) on every bootup. Now I want to stop that from happening, but I cannot find the task anywhere. In Task Scheduler, there is no custom tasks folder, and I made sure to have View/Show Hidden enabled. I've looked through the other folders but there are hundreds of tasks there. Is there a better way than going through them one by one?

Comment: Did you give your task a name?  I look in Admin Tools, Task Scheduler and all the Tasks have names.

Comment: That's the point, I can't find it and I can't remember the exact name. It's something to do with the calendar, but there are no tasks that mention the calendar

Answer (score 4):

One way to do that is to extract all scheduled tasks in a file.

```
schtasks.exe /query /V /FO CSV > scheduledTasks.csv
```

Then you can search directly in this file specific pattern to your tasks.

For example, you can use CTRL+F and search the executable file or script run by your tasks in order to find the line of your scheduled task in the CSV file.

Comment: I'm not technically minded. Where do I type that?

Comment: Use this command in CMD: Windows + R, then type CMD and put the command in the black windows

Comment: I tried it but no file was extracted. Or is there a specific directory I should check?

Comment: The file should appear in your home folder "C:\Users\<username>". You can also directly type the name of the file (scheduledTasks.csv) in the cmd after the first command to open it.

Comment: Ok I got the CSV file but there is no mention of the calendar app. I did searches for all tasks created by me and it's not there. It's like the task isn't logged, but it is still happening every time I boot up. This task was created before I upgraded to Windows 10. Could the upgrade have somehow removed it from the log?

Comment: Actually there are a bunch of tasks called Host Name and the task name on all of them is just TaskName (no details).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this [solution by adenhaan](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0f985ec9-51a5-4ebe-9b83-aec746f18223/where-are-my-custom-scheduled-tasks-they-disappeared-from-all-2008-r2-server?forum=winserverManagement):

> Had very similar experience recently.... created a task, went back
> into task manager and couldn't find a trace of it, after some
> experimenting I found the following;
>
> If you create a task while the "Task scheduler (local)" node is
> selected / highlighted in the left navigation, it appears that the
> task will disappear into a black hole.
>
> If instead you make sure you select/highlight the "Task Scheduler
> Library" node, and then create the task, it will show up and be stored
> in C:\Windows\System32\Tasks and stick.

Comment: In my case, the file is present in "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks", but still doesn't show up in the scheduler...

Comment: @MatheusRocha it is important to click on a certain place in the task scheduler GUI. Please experiment with where you click. As far as I remember, you have to look in the left pane and mark a specific item: It could be either the **folder**, perhaps called "Library", or the **clock** called "Task Manager (local)". Clicking on these items in the left pane shows two different lists of tasks. Admittedly confusing!

Comment: I'm aware of that. In fact my task was in a specific folder, but even after navigating to that folder it would still be empty. It was a weird thing. What I did was to find the task through the file system, back it up, delete the task and its copies from the registry and its files, then re-import the backed copy.

Comment: I had the same problem. Mine showed up after restarted the Task Scheduler UI.